# How to get an active window title between two browser tabs/windows using Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium

I can switch between two tabs/windows but my requirement is to know or get active window between them.

In my project, on a click of a webElement of a page a random pop(tab/window) gets opened and I would like to know whether that(new) window has focus or my original page.

I tried to use JNA Api to get the active window and its title but my web page is
remotely located.

Perfect solution is greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? As you did in school... please show your work. :) It's part of the process of getting questions answered on SO. It's helpful to you because it forces you to investigate your own problem and think it through. It also proves to readers that you did your homework and made a reasonable attempt to answer your own question. Thirdly, it helps readers find and diagnose the problem resulting in a better answer for you and less time wasted for us.

Answer (score 3):

`driver.getTitle()` will give you the title of the page that you can use to determine which page you are on or if you are on the page where you want to be and then use the logic to switch window if required. `getTitle()` returns a `String` and you can use one of the string methods to compare the title, for example:

```
String title = getDriver().getTitle();

if(!title.equals("Expected Title")) {
        //may be you would like to switch window here
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
String title = driver.getTitle()
```

This will give you the title of the page which you can refer to using Selenium to figure out which page the driver is currently on.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote my own method to switch to a window if the window title is known, maybe some of this would be helpful. I used Selenide (Java) methods for this, but if you've got Vanilla WebDriver, you can achieve the same thing

```
/** Switches user to window of user's choice */
      public static void switchToWindow(String windowTitle) {
        WebDriver driver = getWebDriver();
        // Get list of all open tabs - note behaviour may be different between FireFox and Chrome.
        ArrayList<String> tabs = new ArrayList<>(driver.getWindowHandles());
        // iterate through open tabs. If the title of the page is contained in the tab, switch to it.
        for (String windowHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()) {
          String title = getWebDriver().getTitle();
          driver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
          if (title.equalsIgnoreCase(windowTitle)) {
            break;
          }
        }
      }
```

This method might not be lightening fast, but it will iterate through current open windows and check the title matches the one you've specified.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assert the title, you could use the xpath selector:

```
String pageTitle = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//title[text() = 'Title you looking for']"));
```

This is a dumb example with you can surround with try/catch, implement assertions or other technique to have the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, for me this worked. After clicking on the first link of bing search results in edge, my link opened in a new tab. I explicitly mentioned to stay in the same tab.

```
async function switchTab() {
      await driver.getAllWindowHandles().then(async function (handles) {
        await driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);
      });
    }
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
//get initial window handles
Set<String> prevWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
while(true){
      //get current window handles
      Set<String> currWindowHandles = driver.getWindowHandles();
      //if one of the current window handles not equals to
      //any of the previous window handles,switch to this window
      //and prevWindowHandles = currWindowHandles
      for(String prevHandle : prevWindowHandles){
          int noEqualNum = 0;
          for(String currHandle : currWindowHandles){
              if(!currHandle.equals(prevHandle))
                  noEqualNum++
          }
          if(noEqualNum == currWindowHandles.size()){
             driver.switchTo().window(currWindow);
             prevWindowHandles = currWindowHandles;
                    break;
          }

      }
}
```

Comment: Please, provide some text description to your answer. "only-code" answers don't look good

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/349538) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.